# how to raise modal view from tab bar button

Tags: ios

I'm using this:

https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar

Anyone know how to get a modal view raised from say..the camera button (if the camera button were to be used for something else other than the camera)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BaseViewController.m the centre button is added in

```
    -(void) addCenterButtonWithImage:(UIImage*)buttonImage highlightImage:(UIImage*)highlightImage
```

Simply add the observer:

```
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then obviously implement:

```
    -(void)click:(id)sender{
[self presentModalViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
```

}

Comment: Thanks -- which view controller does this present though?

Comment: It will present the view controller you give as argument to presentModalViewController. I have written [[UIViewController alloc] init] for the example.